# Navigate through non-geographical maps

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, image, opengis

I'd need to navigate through and mark non-geographical maps.

I used Leaflet.js example to do that (http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html), and it's working, but my images would be very large and then have to be served as tiles.

So I installed a local OpenStreetMap server with Mapnik and OpenGIS etc, but I can't seem to find a way to create a .pbf file from my image, hence I can't create nor import the "map" using `osm2pgsql`...

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: What do you mean non-geographical? Is it that the rasters aren't geolocated/georeferenced?

Comment: Yep, I need to navigate through a huge image with high zoom level (medical image) and be able to mark spots. Leaflet allows that, but I can't serve my image as tiles, so it's reaaaaally slow :'(

Comment: You can't convert a raster image to a vector map (PBF).

Comment: If you are trying to create tiles from a big image (jpg, tiff, ...) have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13638969/1504487) or gdal2tiles respectively [gdal2tilesp](https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this plugin to GDAL, which makes it easy to create tiles from a non-geographical image and display it afterwards with leaflet: https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet

Comment: This plugin works great with small images, but a 150Mo image needs more than 30 min to be tiled, and tiles are mixed when you convert 2 images.

Any other tool to help me tile large images ?

Comment: Tiling the image takes a while, that is right. Did you also try the multiprocess version of the script, depending on your computer this should speed it up quite a bit. However I don't understand the part with the mixed images. You can tile every image separately and include it also separate from each other to your leaflet map.